# solving max cut problem on a huge graph (500 x 500) using Semidefinite Programming with CVXOPT

Tags: graphs, optimization, max-cut

So I am learning to do SDP relaxation on graph problems, and for this max cut problem I am given a 500*500 graph, and I am using the straightforward 
relaxation. $W$ is the weight matrix, $X = u u^T$ where $u$ is the original variables.

$$ \max < (I-W),X> $$
$$ s.t. X_{ii} = 1, \forall i$$
$$ X \succeq 0$$

**Problem is:**

The solver I am using is CVXOPT, for which I have to convert X into a *REALLY* long variable, and for CVXOPT I have to paraphrase the constraint into huge matrices (largest ~ 250000 * 125250, but sparse), and load them into the `cvxopt.solver.sdp()`, but at this line python simply gives up and crashes (jupyter notebook says the kernel has died). I have used CVXOPT's sparse matrix feature for the massive constraint matrices (cost vector must be dense), and it's still not working out.

So my question is: is there any way to work around this? I'm open to *anything*, rephrasing the problem, using a different solver, or maybe just write the damped newton method for log barrier method myself. I am contemplating about CVXPY, but seeing that it uses CVXOPT as one of its solvers, I don't think I want to waste my time if it's gonna come out the same, and similar reason for writing my own program.

Comment: When you say 500*500 graph, do you mean the graph has 500 vertices?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [scicomp.se].

Comment: yeah sorry, I meant 500 vertices (500*500 adj matrix)